# Reload own created UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I got a custom UITableViewcell which should load an Image when use that code:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]];
        imageView.image = image;
        NSLog(@"test");
    });
}
```

It loads the Image very fast, so I get the response "test" very fast, but it needs to load IN the tableView. Also if I select the row it loads the Image.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As long as setImageWithURL: is called as an effect of cellForRowAtIndexPath, then it should should show up as you expect... however, you need to call imageView.image = image; on the main thread.  This goes for ALL UI related tasks.  So you'll want:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageView.image = image;
            NSLog(@"test");
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT:

Using NSOperationQueue.

Create an operation queue as a member of your view controller.

```
    m_operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    m_operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 // if you want to load images in order;
```

Make sure you cancel operations when the view unloads and when the table will refresh using

```
    [m_operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Do your thing in setImageWithURL

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    [m_operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageView.image = image;
            NSLog(@"test");
        });
    }];
}
```

EDIT again:

Sorry, forgot that setImage was in your custom table cell.  You can either:

1) make it a static object that you initialize in the +(void)initialize; method of your cell
2) make it a static object available via class method on your view controller
2) make a singleton instance that is available to your table cell

The design preference is up to you and depends what other practices you've been using if you want to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you SOO much, now I have an other question: Why don't all the people use this way, I think that is MUCH easier then the normal LazyTableViewCells.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LazyTableViewCells (is it normal? first I've heard of it), but given that it's a third party API (correct?), my guess is that it's purpose was to provide something the OS didn't.  I think GCD was introduced in iOS 3.2, so perhaps there wasn't an easy way to accomplish this before then. Something important to note though... all these repeated calls to dispatch_async might create a LOT of threads.  LazyTableViewCells seems to download images synchronously, hopefully using only 1 thread.  Might be better to use an NSOperationQueue for this kind of thing.

Comment: Well, I wrote it wrong, it's called "LazyTableImages", here's the link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I figured that was it, because thats the closest thing I could find when looking for it.  My comment applied to that.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [tableView reloadData] when you finish downloading the image.

There is a similar question with an accepted answer, but also it has a suggestion to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Take a look: [How to get UITableViewCell images to update to downloaded images without having to scroll UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874505/how-to-get-uitableviewcell-images-to-update-to-downloaded-images-without-having)

Comment: If I understand the question, reloadData is not what you want.  This will trigger complete recalculation of table rows, recreation/reuse of table cells... and in prepareForReuse you probably are or want to clear the imageView image, so it doesn't show up in the wrong cell.